# PHP include not functioning

Tags: php, include

I can't manage to figure out why in the world I can't get the include function to work on my website (I should specify that my web host does allow PHP, and that all my files have .php extensions). Basically, when I test it out, and look at the source code, the footer.php file content doesn't appear...

I'm using this to call the footer:

```
<?php include("/media/global/footer/footer.php"); ?>
```

And this is my footer.php file:

```
<footer id="globalfooter">

    <!-- Left section -->
    <div class="gf-left">
        <!-- Copyright -->
        <a id="gf-copyright" href="/copyright/">Copyright &copy; 2013 Hugo Clarke-Wing. Some rights reserved.</a>
        <!-- CC -->
        <a id="gf-cc" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/deed.en_US"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Right section -->
    <div class="gf-right">
        <ul id="gf-pipednav">
            <li><a href="/sitemap/">Site Map</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact/">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="/privacy/">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</footer>
```

Comment: Have you checked the directory path if correct?

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: I doubt the file is at `/media/global/...` **from the root of your filesystem.**

Comment: Yes I think christian is right your file path given might be gone.

Comment: What do you mean by _the root of my filesystem_? This is the path from the root of the website. Sorry, I'm very very new to PHP...

Comment: `include` uses paths in the local file system, not URLs which are used to access the system over the web. The URL may be `/media/...`, but on your harddisk it's `C:\Users\clarkewingh\Projects\foo\media\..` (guessing, obviously). You need *that* path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `../` solution didn't appear to work for me. So I ultimately decided to go with a different approach:

```
<?php 
$path_footer = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path_footer .= "/media/global/footer/footer.php";
include($path_footer);
?>
```

And that worked flawlessly, even though it was far from a direct approach...

Answer (score 1):

If media is your root directory...Try this it might work for you

```
<?php include("../media/global/footer/footer.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use require_once().

Why?
Because then you're sure that it is included, else it wil give an error.
This will give you more ways to debug your code.

Edit:

You shouldn't go to the file from root.